# SimplePie Parsing - Create List From Content

Tags: parsing, formatting, rss, simplepie

I'm using the RSSSimplePie plugin on CMS Made Simple.

The feed I am using is this [Tide Times](https://www.tidetimes.org.uk/stoke-gabriel-duncannon-tide-times.rss). I would like to display the times and heights as an inline list? At present each item has a br tag so starts on a new line.

The template I have is this:

```
<div class="feeds">{foreach from=$feeds item=onefeed}
<div class="feed-content">
    {$onefeed->get_content()}
</div>
{/foreach}</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably will need to create a plugin or pass it to a UDT for parsing in PHP.

Using http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php should be able to quick parse and pull out the variables that you need.